# Can I deactivate Battlefield 3 Limited?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have BF3 for the PS3 which I bought when came out but have not really used so thought I would sell them to someone who would use them.

Is there a way to do this and pass on the key to a new user and deactivate it against my accounts? Just seems a waste.

Comment: This is two questions about two different online systems, so you might want to limit yourself to just one.  I'd change this to ask just about BF3 - we've covered whether or not you can [give away](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/giving-away-steam-games) or [split accounts/games](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6594/is-it-possible-to-split-a-steam-account) from your Steam account before (spoiler alert: No.)

Comment: I've gone ahead and made the edit, hope that's OK.

Comment: Battlefield 3 is on Steam? What did I miss?

Comment: @Maxorq, originally the question referred to MW3 on PC (which requires Steam) as well as BF3 on the PS3.

Comment: @agent86 oh, what the hell

Comment: you should mark an answer so this question gets marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

As @agent86 said in the comments, you can't deactivate a game on Steam. However, on PS3, it is possible to deactivate a game (apparently you can do this once) and transfer it to another console. Here's a thread on how games relate to your console:
http://community.us.playstation.com/thread/3903197?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. Yes, you can deactivate it on your console, but it is still tied to your personal account so that you can then activate it elsewhere e.g if your PS3 broke. The codes to play online are useable only once and cannot be transferred or sold to another person/account. The whole reason the codes exist is to generate cash that is missed through second hand sales which is exactly what you are doing.